# Can't store other language data in nvarchar column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nvarchar

I am using SQL Server 2008.
This is my Table definition.

```
create table myTable (nid int identity(1,1),content nvarchar(max));
```

when I execute these two queries

```
insert into myTable(content)values(N'हिंदी में परीक्षण');
update myTable set content=N'हिंदी में परीक्षण' where nid=1;
```

the other language data is inserted/updated in the table. I want to do the same in a stored procedure. This is the definition of my stored procedure.

```
create proc myProc
@nid int,
@content nvarchar(max)
as
begin
  update myTable set content=@content where nid=@nid;
end
```

it just doesn't work the column is updated with ????????????? value. What should I do. I tried to do this

```
update myTable set content=N''+@content where nid=@nid;
```

But this doesn't work as well. Please Help.

I forgot to tell one thing

```
exec myProc 1,N'हिंदी में परीक्षण'
```

this does work of course it does the problem is i send data from an asp .net web application where i use this syntax.

```
public void myProcCall()
    {
        dbcommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("myProc", nid, content);
        ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbcommand);
    }
```

So when I send other language content from the web application the value is updated as ??????????. Do I have to make some changes in my asp .net code.

Comment: You *can* store any language. You can store any UTF16 character. MySQL doesn't have `nvarchar` though. If you can't get it to work in SQL Server, it's because you *don't* send a Unicode string or the field is not Unicode. Whatever loads the text mangled the string

Comment: Show us the code that calls the proc.

Comment: BTW `nvarchar(max)` is meant for blobs that can grow to 2GB, not normal text

Comment: Post the code that calls the stored procedure. That's what converts Unicode to ASCII and mangles the data

Comment: `update myTable set content=N''+@content where nid=@nid;` is pointless. First, it prepends an empty string. Second `N'whatever'` is used for *string literals*. An `nvarchar` parameter is already known to be nvarchar, it doesn't need any prefixes. Whatever calls the stored procedure mangled the text before it reach the server

Comment: I tried this `exec myProc 1,N'हिंदी में'`. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
EXEC myProc 1, N'हिं में पदी रीक्षण'
```

This won't

```
EXEC myProc 1, 'हिं में पदी रीक्षण'
```

Ergo, the parameter is sent as *non-unicode*

You need to ensure that the code that populate the parameter sends unicode